# Blender Game Engine - Reporting Correct Angles?

Tags: game-engine

New to blender game engine.. The image shows console window, blender and a simple python script to report current angles associated with a camera. I set angles for X, Y and Z to be 135, 0 and 135, just to show a sample case of weird angles being reported.

If played, console shows angles as -45, 180 and -45. Is this an expected behavior?

Thanks,
Chandra

[image: Blender Game Engine Reporting Angles Weird]

Comment: I've just tried the same setup and it is outputing the right values (135, 0, 135) try first outputing the values before conversion

Comment: Many thanks for setting up and trying it Chebhou. Blender seems to take 135 as 135 most of the times, but as 134.99 occassionally, don't know the reason. Kindly type 136 for angle x, chances are high to get weird values reported. 

I have attached another image with another combination of position and angle reporting in unexpected way. 

By the way, 'before conversion' means conversion to degrees (unlikely) or to euler? I tried both in the new snapshot attached..